# Learning GNU C 2.4 cowsdf?

Tags: c

I'm reading through [Learning GNU C](http://nongnu.askapache.com/c-prog-book/learning_gnu_c.html) and [Section 2.4](http://nongnu.askapache.com/c-prog-book/learning_gnu_c.html#cowsdf) is titled "cowsdf".

What does **cowsdf** mean? Is it some mysterious programming acronym or nonsense or something very obvious I've missed?

Comment: It seems book there is broken, here is correct one http://www.nongnu.org/c-prog-book/online/c355.html#AEN369

Comment: @rpd That is probably the joke of the section, as it describe some hint as how to name variables to make the code readable.

Comment: @myaut: That's a link to an older version of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cowsdf` has no particular meaning. It's probably just a placeholder in the manuscript for a better title later.

There's also `titlesdf` earlier, which I would apply the same lack of meaning to.

By looking at the [source code](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/c-prog-book/learning_gnu_c.texinfo?root=c-prog-book&view=markup) to the book, we can see that it is still `cowsdf` in the most recent version of the book as well. And we can see that the book was most recently edited 6 years ago. So it's unlikely that this will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Bill & myaut for your helpful replies. I'll put it down as a manuscript author/editing error and move on to learning GNU C...best wishes :-)

Comment: Just as a follow up, I have found online "The GNU C programming Tutorial" by M Burgess and I'm looking at this now and the 2 tutorials are somewhat different (both on GNU C of course). See http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctut.pdf